# Создал установщик проекта на C#, установил у себя — всё работает. Установил на других пк — функционал работает не полностью!

Tags: c#, office-interop, backgroundworker, setup, печать

У меня есть проект на **C#**, он не очень большой и сложный. Делал сам. При запуске она отображается в trayicon(там, где часы). Моя программа в фоновом режиме(в компоненте backgroundworker), с помощью класса `FileSystemWatcher`, отлавливает текущие задания на печать и отображает в listView информацию в колонках об текущей печати. Также она в момент перехвата печати, в главном методе программы, с помощью  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` определяет активную книгу Excel, и сравнивая её имя с именем текущего задания на печать, получает полный путь к активной книге Excel. А теперь **ВНИМАНИЕ!** сохраняет путь(*string*) в текстовый документ(`WorkBooks.config`). Потом либо при перезагрузки пк, либо при открытии программы из трея, при событии `onLoad`программа из текстового документа получает пути к файлам, имя, `ExcelType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`, после чего отправляет документы в *Google Drive*, облако. Теперь сама проблема. Я создал установщик, используя [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Версию .Net Framework использовал то 4.6.1 , то 4.7.2 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выходные файлы такие: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Библиотеки такие использовал(Для MainForm):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
using File = Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
```

Вот как выглядит результат работы программы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На моём пк работает нормально. А вот при попытки поставить программу на ноутбуке, на пк моего брата, на пк заказчика — моя программа устанавливается, запускается, но функционал не работает либо вообще, либо работает не полностью. Например, в одной из версии моей программы только при открытии от имени администратора выполнялся код добавления информации об текущей печати в listView, но не выполнялся код создания и записи в текстовый документ!!! Почему???. Путь находится в моих документах, и если такого пути нету, то я его создаю программно каждый раз, (а после выполнения загрузки в диск, код программы должен удалять файл с путями). Вот фото с ноутбука [image: введите сюда описание изображения] При этом в папке для путей ничего не появляется [image: введите сюда описание изображения] . И так на пк брата и на пк заказчика. Кстати у меня ОС Windows 10 pro и на ноутбуке, у брата 32-битная 7-ка, у заказчика 64-битная 7-ка. Что делать подскажите люди... Я потратил ого сколько часов на всё про всё. Я так больше не могу:\ . Заранее спасибо) Ниже последняя версия кода главного метода программы)

```
private void GetMainAction(ref int number, ref string Title, ref string CurrentDateTime)
        {
            try
            {
                LocalPrintServer server = new LocalPrintServer();
                foreach (PrintSystemJobInfo jobInfo in server.DefaultPrintQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection())
                {
                    jobInfo.Pause();
                    jobInfo.Cancel();

                    number = jobInfo.JobIdentifier;
                    Title = jobInfo.Name;
                    CurrentDateTime = Convert.ToString(jobInfo.TimeJobSubmitted);// TimeJobSubmitted 

                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] {
                                 number.ToString(),
                                 Title,
                                 CurrentDateTime
                                 });                   

                    Excel oExcelApp = (Excel)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
                    for (int i = 0; i < oExcelApp.Windows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        ExcelfilePath = oExcelApp.Windows.get_Item(i + 1).Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;
                    }
                    ExcelfilePath = $@"{ExcelfilePath}";
                    ExcelFileName = Path.GetFileName(ExcelfilePath);

                    // создаем каталог для файла Workbooks.config
                    PrintLogWorkbooksFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);//Путь к файлу мои документы
                    PrintLogWorkbooksFilePath = Path.Combine(PrintLogWorkbooksFilePath, "Catching Excel Workbooks", "Scheduled Dispatch");//Записываем сюда .config файл с заданиями для отправки в облако

                    DirectoryInfo dirInf = new DirectoryInfo(PrintLogWorkbooksFilePath);
                    if (!dirInf.Exists)
                    {
                        dirInf.Create();
                    }

                    if (Title == ExcelFileName)
                    {
                        string WorkbooksConfigPath = PrintLogWorkbooksFilePath + @"\Workbooks.config";
                        try
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(WorkbooksConfigPath, true, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLineAsync(ExcelfilePath);
                                //sw.Flush();
                            }
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }

                    this.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                    {
                        listView1.Items.Add(item);
                    }));

                    while (jobInfo.IsPaused == false && jobInfo.IsCompleted == false)
                    {
                        jobInfo.Pause();
                        jobInfo.Cancel();                  
                    }

                    if (jobInfo.IsPaused && jobInfo.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        this.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                        {
                            RemoveDuplicateitems();
                            WriterAsync(listView1, "   ", "   ");
                        }));
                    }                                                                            
                }              
            }
            catch { }           
        }
```

- ссылка на pdf файл из скриншотов процесса работы программы у заказчика 
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KMIPYGbvRc65JnVsncuwTsufr0laIjhl

Comment: Нельзя прятать исключения. Если не нужно показывать пользователю, то можно писать в лог. Лог может быть реализован по разному: файл, журнал виндоуз. Но раз у вас проблемы с файловой системой, то можно начать с долги лога собственно в интерфейс формы. Заведите какой-нибудь компонент listbox и пишите туда. Помимо ошибки, можно добавить вводные данные.

Comment: Нужен stacktrace ошибок. Иначе можно долго "гадать на кофейной гуще", что вызывает проблемы. А, насчёт исключений, я полностью согласен с @4per (даже добавить нечего).

Comment: У меня на ноутбуке появляются ошибки такие и только такие: 1)RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATE; 2) MK_E_UNAVAILABLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Предисловие:** я уже давно переписал свою программу на WPF.
**Решение:** При запуске приложения от имени администратора отключается виртуализация файловой системы и реестра. Возможности библиотеки ole32.dll, которую я импортировал и использовал, были ограничены при отключении виртуализации, а конкретно в моём случае оказалось, что она не смогла найти активных открытых файлов в программах при отключении виртуализации — это была одна из ключевых внутренних функций программы. А без запуска от имени администратора программа не хотела писать в файлы на другом пк! И не важно по какому пути она писала: на диск C:, D:, AppData и тд результата без привилегий не было. Обычное консольное приложение .NET Core может писать без прав админа на другом пк, а моя программа нет. Вот и получилось что моя программа требовала функционала, который взаимоисключает себя. Пробовал и через общую разделяемую память передавать данные, разделив свою одну программу на две и так и сяк у тут уже у меня вылезла специфика потоков и специфика печати. То есть разобравшись с потоками печати решение будет такое: разделить свою одну программу на две, через общую разделяемую память передавать данные.

Answer (score 0):

1. Исключения должны обрабатываться у вас программа работает т.к необходимые библиотеки установлены , а у брата и клиента нет.
2. **Программа запускается а функционал не работает**
   не работает потому что есть ошибки которые вылетают и код не отрабатывает как должен и вы про это не чего не знаете потому что у вас блок обработки исключений пустой.
3. **При этом в папке для путей ничего не появляется** а код отработал как надо ? или у вас нету прав чтобы создавать документы в этой папке или путь у казан не верный но вы об этом не чего не знаете.
4. Установщик лучше делать самому предварительно собрав все нужные файлы для этого можно использовать одну из программ для создания типа install maker или похожих
5. **Решение** попробуйте это (мне это помогло) откройте свойства проекта Properties->Publish->Application Files везде установите **include** и **Required** [image: Application Files]
6. нажмите Publish wizard настройте путь куда все собрать
7. Откройте папку в которую вы собрали проект внутри нее будет папка Application Files и в ней под папка с вашим проектом и библиотеками эту папку с копируйте на другой компьютер(брата или заказчика) и из нее запустите вашу программу все должно работать.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, в итоге у меня программа даже на моём пк не запустилась. Ещё интересная деталь: после обновлений MS VS моя программа у меня же не работает и приходится код как-то видоизменять немного либо просто много раз запускать старый чтобы начала она работать(выглядит так). Добавил заново вывод сообщений об ошибках, они дают такие сообщения, и кстати теперь программа на моём пк ведёт также как на ноуте, после обновы MS VS

Comment: Пришлите скрин папки Application Files , если все библиотеки которые ему нужны лежат в папке с проектом он должен был запустится

Comment: У меня на ноутбуке появляются ошибки такие и только такие: 1)RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATE; 2) MK_E_UNAVAILABLE.

Comment: вот посмотри https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073754/error-exception-from-hresult-0x8001010a-rpc-e-servercall-retrylater а вобше я просил скрин папки

Comment: Не знаю как прислать скрин в комментариях, но библиотеки есть, программа устанавливалась, но по нажатию на неё мышкой просто не запускалась.

Comment: Вот) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aSwtllyPzKemhLQdaHG83CWlikqRwSMo

Comment: убери со всех файлов расширение .deploy и запусти потом .ехе прям из папки Application Files